# Phase transitions, Landau Ginzburg theory and Symmetry reduction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

On one side of critical temperature (usually for $T<T_{c}$), symmetry is reduced w.r.t the symmetry on the other (usually $T>T_{c}$) regime. I heard on the road (near a theoretical physics institute) that the symmetry group for $T<T_{c}$ has to be a subgroup of the symmetry group for $T>T_{c}$. Can one prove this for both 1st and higher order transitions ?

Also, I found that the phases which one can generate in the regime below $T_{c}$ are the ones which obey the symmetry properties of the Landau free energy expression we start with.

For example, for structural phase transition of $BaTiO_{3}$ with cubic symmetry for $T>T_{c}$, depending on whether I expand the free energy to 4th order or 8th order respectively (cubic symmetry of $BaTiO_{3}$ for $T>T_{c}$ kept into account), I get different number of possible phases (2 and 3 respectively) below the critical temperature but as expected, all are subgroups of the cubic symmetry group.

Can one generate all possible symmetry subgroups of G for $T<T_{c}$ i.e. all possible phases starting from a particular phase for $T>T_c $ (with a given symmetry group G), depending on what order expansion is used for the Landau free energy ?

Also, does the validity of hyperscaling within the a certain region of temperature around the critical temperature (which is of the order of the region of smearing of the transition curve around $T_c$) for continuous phase transitions as above, imply anything for the reduction in symmetry around $T=T_{c}$ ?